Problem in working with RadioButton GroupName
I have a problem - I have multiple radio buttons with the same group name.
I have button with backend code for example degg26.Checked = True;
when I click the button, it should check the degg26 value.
Let's suppose that I have manually checked any radio button before degg26, and after that I click on the button, code works and degg26 is checked.
If I was manually checked any radio button after degg26, and after that I click on the button, nothing works and degg26 wasn't checked
Any help ?!
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="tecTaqeem2.aspx.vb" Inherits="tecTaqeem2" %>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg20" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"   
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="0" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg23" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"  
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="3" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg24" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"   
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="4" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg25" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"   
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="5" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg26" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"   
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="6" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg27" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"  
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="7" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg28" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"  
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="8" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg29" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"   
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="9" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="degg210" CssClass="ChkBoxClassTxt" runat="server"   
            style="font-size:20px; color:black; margin:0px; height: 10px; width:10px; accent-color:red;" GroupName="G2" Text="10" />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>


Short answer: use RadioButtonList instead of grouping radio buttons.
What happened: even when you only see one checked option, in Asp.Net there are no restrictions for groups to have more than one checked item and this is what's happening. Internally you end up having two radios checked in code behind and in the resulting html source code.
The browser then decides which one to show as checked: typically the last one that appear checked in the html source code.
Example:

You manually check "2" and "6" by code. Browser shows "6" as checked.
You manually check "8" and "6" by code. Browser shows "8" as checked.

The reason why you have maximum two checked radios internally in code behind, it's because the browser is posting back the one checked by user, while you check one by code.

thank you so much for your answer
I will use RadioButtonList
